# Суммирование значений таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Дорогие друзья, есть такая таблица в mysql [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой запрос составить чтобы суммировать количество фирм по городам независимо от колонки промышленность. Например чтоб было так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли будет если сделать так ?

```
SELECT Название_города,SUM(кол-во_фирм)
FROM mysql_table
GROUP BY Название города;
```

Comment: Да, правильно. PS. Порой быстрее попробовать, чем спросить и ждать ответа...